# Define the behavior of operators without built-in meaning

Tags: symbolic, syntax, operators, built-in-symbols

I need an operation $\tilde{}$ that *lifts another operation* (for example, the sum, but this does not have to be limited to real numbers) in the sense that $\widetilde{ (x \oplus y)} = \tilde x + \tilde y $.

I tried to implement this

```
Til[x⊕y] 
Til[x_CirclePlus] := Til[#] & /@ x
Til[x ⊕ y]
```

where `Til` is the tilde. But this yields $ \widetilde{ (x \oplus y)} = \tilde x \color{red}\oplus \tilde y $.

- How to replace the red plus by a normal sum?
- Alternatively, how can I read each of the summands without using `x_CirclePlus`?

Comment: `Til[CirclePlus[a_, b_]] := Til[a] + Til[b]`? If I understand you correctly, you would not need your other definition if you use this one.

Comment: As a further generalization of @Marco's proposal: `Til[CirclePlus[args__]] := Apply[Plus, Til /@ {args}]`.

Comment: Great, that's the solution. I don't know why I doubted `Til` cannot read directly the arguments of `CirclePlus`. As for the second, I didn't know that syntax, sorry. Both work.

Comment: Despite your second bullet, the following works too and is close to your original: `Til[x_CirclePlus] := Til /@ Plus@@x`; it is just a slightly shorter version of @J.M.'s `Til[CirlePlus[args__]]:=Plus@@(Til/@{args})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments:

```
ClearAll[Til]
Til[CirclePlus[args__]] := Apply[Plus, Til /@ {args}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[Til]

Til[a_⊕b___] := Til /@ Unevaluated[a + b]
```